# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with' in function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query but I am getting a syntax error near the keyword 'with'. But I am not able to understand how to fix it. I am using SQL Server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(@N INT) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        /* Write your T-SQL query statement below. */
        with result as (
          select salary, 
          dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) as salary_rank
          from employee
      )
      select salary 
      from result 
      where result.salary_rank = N

    );
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a Scalar-Valued User-Defined function, so you assign a local variable of the return type and then `return` it.

EG

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(@N INT) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    declare @rv int;

    with result as 
    (
        select salary, 
        dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) as salary_rank
        from employee
    )
    select @rv = salary 
    from result 
    where result.salary_rank = @N;

    return @rv;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try inlining the CTE here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(@N INT) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        SELECT salary
        FROM
        (
            SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS salary_rank
            FROM employee
        ) t
        WHERE salary_rank = @N
END
```